# React AppContext defaultValue vs Provider value

Tags: reactjs, use-context

I'm trying to create a notification bar to show messages to the user.
I want to be able to add a message to the notificatio bar from any component in a easy way.

I'm usiing React with TypeScript in a NextJs application.

```js
import { FC, createContext, useContext, useState } from "react"

interface Notification {
  message:string
  type: "info" | "success"
}

interface Props {
  notifications:Notification[],
  addNotification: (message:string, type: "info" | "success") => void
}

const defaultValues:Props = {notifications:[], addNotification:() => { alert("not implemented")}}
const MessagesContext = createContext<Props>(defaultValues);

const NotificationProvider:FC = ({children}) => {
  const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([] as Notification[]);
  const addNotification = (message:string, type: "info" | "success") => setNotifications([...notifications, {message, type}])
  return <MessagesContext.Provider value={{notifications, addNotification: addNotification}}>{children}</MessagesContext.Provider>
}

const useNotifications = () => useContext(MessagesContext);

export {NotificationProvider, useNotifications}
```

My problem is that it is showing the alert "not implemented" instead of the wanted implementation of *addNotification*.

Dummy example of usage:

```js
export default function Home() {
  const notifications = useNotifications()
  return <>
  <NotificationProvider>
  <Button onClick={() => notifications.addNotification("click", "success")}>Click</Button>
  <div>notifications: {notifications.notifications.length}</div>
  </NotificationProvider>
  </>}
```

*createContext* defaulValues in mandatory, but where it is creatd I cannot have access to anything that use *useState*.
Also, if it is using the default values, where/when the objects passed with the *value* property are used?

Comment: Did you make sure that the component is nested inside `NotificationProvider`?

Comment: yes, I updated the question with a simple example of usage.

Comment: In your example `useNotifications` is called outside the provider. It must be called from within a component child of the provider.

Comment: bingo!   
I moved the NotificationProvider in the app.js (where I wanted it in the end, I was just experimenting in single page in this example) and the notifications counter works. 
Thanks!